# Radon transform of a delta function results in a sine function

Tags: dirac-delta, integral-transforms

[image]

I took a screenshot from an online video explanation about the Radon transform. It is stated that the radon transform of a delta function (right graph) results in a sine function. Can someone please explain to me, how one gets the graph of a sine function from this? I am not familiar with integral projections and thus have a weak intuition for it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not a complete specification of the Radon transform.

Comment: Let $f(x, y) = \delta((x, y) - (x_0, y_0))$. If we take a line that doesn't go through $(x_0, y_0)$, the integral of $f(x, y)$ is zero. So $\mathcal R[f]$ is localized on the curve $t = t_0 \cos(\theta - \theta_0)$. If $(t, \theta)$ lies on that curve, the one-dimensional integral of $f$ leaves a one-dimensional delta function. A more straightforward derivation is
$$\mathcal R[f](t, \theta) =
\mathcal F^{-1}[\tau \mapsto
 \mathcal F[f](\tau \cos \theta, \tau \sin \theta)](t) =
\delta(t - x_0 \cos \theta - y_0 \sin \theta).$$

Comment: Thanks. Still, how does one now obtain from that, that the Radon transform looks as in the picture above?

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed $\theta$ there is only one $t$ for which the line $t=x_1\cos(\theta)+x_2\sin(\theta)$ crosses the point $(a,b)$, namely

$t_{a,b}(\theta):=a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta)$. The curve depicted in the video you watched is the curve $(\theta,t_{a,b}(\theta))$ on the plane $t-\theta$.

[image]